# Can't display HTML tags on error in PHP 7

Tags: php, html

With this ini settings:

```
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log",APP_LOG);
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);
ini_set("log_errors_max_len",1024);
ini_set("docref_root","http://manual/en/");
ini_set("html_errors",1);
```

I normally get HTML tags on displaing errors my PHP version is 7.0.22

Comment: Can you give us an example of the type of error message that you are expecting and when you are expecting it?

Comment: I get all messages in correct  way but are displayed in plain text, 
normally they are formatted with html tags with a table for the stack trace.
now satck trace is a single string without new lines very difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning on xdebug in your php.ini file. Then restart your web server.

Answer (score 0):

`ini_set("html_errors",true)`; will be correct settings and after setting your setting, restart your php server.

if you want to use `error_handling` in `php-7` , it will handle this way:

```
try{
     // Your code
} 
catch(Error $e) {
    $trace = $e->getTrace();
    echo $e->getMessage().' in '.$e->getFile().' on line '.$e->getLine().' called from '.$trace[0]['file'].' on line '.$trace[0]['line'];
}
```

Comment: true | 1 as shown above is the same.  it doesn't work!

Comment: you dont have this also: ini_set("display_errors", 1) ;
error_reporting(E_ALL);